# How to get the latitude and longitude between two points in sequence?

Tags: android, google-maps

**Explanation:** I have some requirement two get the all the latitude and longitude between origin and destination.I have got it. The problem is it's not coming into the sequence.

**For Example:** If I have set origin is "Delhi" and my destination is "Mumbai". So I need a lat & long between these two points. First must be near to the Delhi because of my origin is "Delhi". Google Direction API provided me the arbitrary way. Sometimes it takes near to the "Mumbai" and then it is going back to return the near of the Delhi.

Please help me solve this problem or if you know how to get all the lat & long in sequence please put your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the direction api

```
// Origin of route
String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;

// Destination of route
String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;

// Sensor enabled
String sensor = "sensor=false";

// Building the parameters to the web service
String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor;

// Output format
String output = "json";
// Building the url to the web service
String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;
```

download the lat long list from the above url and use that list to get specific lat long.